# How can I adjust the query below to show transition time into the next status in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, time

The pivot query below gathers the time spent by status only. If a status is in NEW for example (sorted in ascending order by customer_update_date - grouped by ticket number), the query will not get the transition time into the next status (as it is truly in the same status until the next update in a different status).

Say for this example is in NEW status from 8/23/16 01:00:00 PM to 8/23/16 02:00:00 PM (1 hour). BUT, from the update sequence where NEW goes to PENDING, the time stamp is 8/23/16 04:00:00 PM, which means it was still in NEW for 2 additional hours.

Is there any way possible the query below can be adjusted to add the transition time from status to status and group that additional time on whatever the status was previously shown? I hope this makes sense. Thank you so much for your time.

```
WITH t AS (
    select 
        ticket_number,
        ISNULL(status,'null') status,
        update_date,
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ticket_number ORDER BY update_date) rn
    from xxx.dbo.report
), s AS (
    SELECT 
        t1.ticket_number,
        t1.status,
        t1.update_date,
        t2.update_date prevdate,
        case when t2.status=t1.status then DATEDIFF(s, t2.update_date, t1.update_date) end dif
    FROM t t1
    LEFT JOIN t t2 ON t1.ticket_number=t2.ticket_number AND t1.rn=t2.rn+1
)
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        ticket_number,
        [status],
        cast(dateadd(s,sum(dif),0) as time(0)) [time]
    FROM s
    GROUP BY ticket_number,status )  src
PIVOT
(
  min([time])
  for [status] in ([Closed], [Complete], [New], [Waiting-1], [Waiting-2], [Waiting-3], [StopTime], [Research-1], [Research-2], [Resolved], [Special Request], [Opened Request], [null])
) piv
```

Comment: please show some sample data and expected result and explain along with it

Comment: even better, provide code that generates the sample data so all we have to do is change the query.  Also, it looks the PIVOT is not essential to the question, consider removing it and simplifying the request.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want the minimum row for each status, then to calculate the time between those two rows.  This code below will do that, along with some sample data.

```
--create table dbo.report (ticket_number int, status varchar(50), update_date datetime)
--delete from report
--insert into report values (1, 'New', '20160823 13:00')
--insert into report values (1, 'New', '20160823 14:00')
--insert into report values (1, 'Pending', '20160823 16:00')

WITH ticketstatus AS 
(
    SELECT 
        ticket_number,
        ISNULL(status,'null') status,
        update_date,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ticket_number,status ORDER BY update_date) statusrn  -- will provide us with minimum status rows
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ticket_number ORDER BY update_date) ticketrn  -- will tell us which 
    FROM 
        dbo.report
), 
-- get the first row for each status change
minticketstatus AS
(
    SELECT * FROM ticketstatus where statusrn = 1
)
, statuschange as
 (
    SELECT 
        t1.ticket_number
        ,t1.status Status
        ,t1.update_date t1updatedate
        ,t2.status 'StatusChangedTo'
        ,t2.update_date 'StatusChangedDate'
        ,datediff(hh, t1.update_date, t2.update_date) 'time (in hours)'
    FROM minticketstatus t1
    LEFT JOIN minticketstatus t2 ON t2.ticket_number=t1.ticket_number AND t2.status <> t1.status and t2.update_date > t1.update_date
)
SELECT
*   
FROM 
    statuschange
```